# Magento 1.9.1.1 PayPal XPath Invalid Expression

Tags: magento-1.9, module, paypal, ce-1.9.1.1

There seems to be a bug in the new Magento 1.9.1.1

Found this in /var/log/system.log

```
2015-06-17T15:11:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed  in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Observer.php on line 132
```

The XPath causing the issue is

```
$paymentsConfigs = $paymentGroups->xpath('paypal_payments/*/backend_config/' . $countryCode);
```

Can anyone see an obvious problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's missing a slash in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Observer.php line 142.

```
$paymentsConfigs = $paymentGroups->xpath('paypal_payments/\*' . $countryCode);
```

should be

```
$paymentsConfigs = $paymentGroups->xpath('paypal_payments/\*/' . $countryCode);
```

The original code results in 'paypal_payments/*NL' instead of 'paypal_payments/*/NL'.

Hope it answers your question.